# Setting Oracle Type Conversion off

Tags: database, oracle, type-conversion

We have a very large code base and in the code there are so many type conversions like updating number fields with quotes '1' updating varchar2 fields with numbers without quotes etc.

Is there a flag to turn this feature off for testing so we track our code and fix this operations that forces db to type conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no.

Assuming that you are using at least 10g, you can [enable compile-time warnings](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/plsql-enhancements-10g.php#compile_time_warnings).  That will generate warnings for some type conversions but generally only those that potentially [create potential performance issues.](http://psoug.org/reference/plsql_warnings.html)  Of course, that assumes that the type conversions in question are happening in PL/SQL not in random SQL statements that are being executed from SQL*Plus or from some client application.

Comment: yes i think you are right, no way to do that. We are using 11g. Enabling compile-time warnings not a good solution for me for now ;)